# Will android:alwaysRetainTaskState flag save the activity intent?

Tags: android

Suppose the current task stack of my app P contains activities: A B. A started B with some intent i.

A is defined with android:alwaysRetainTaskState flag.

Then user switched to other app, and after a while the process of P is killed by OS.

Then user started P from home screen. Since A has android:alwaysRetainTaskState flag, the stack will be restored to A B, and B is visible. My understanding is that, only B.onCreate() will be called and A.onCreate() will not be called. Am I right?

Besides, at the moment, does B still have the intent i? That is, when B calls getIntent(), will getIntent() returns null or an intent object, i?

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the given answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that, only B.onCreate() will be called and A.onCreate() will not be called. Am I right?

Yes, you are.

> Besides, at the moment, does B still have the intent i? That is, when B calls getIntent(), will getIntent() returns null or an intent object, i?

getIntent() will work as always - it will return Intent object equal to one you have passed from activity A (not the same instance, but deserialized one)

This answer comes from my experiments (with android 2.3), but it fits neatly into Android's ideology of independent activities (IMHO it's the only reason why Intent can contain only serializable data even when it's used within one application), so I believe it's true for all android versions.

And "alwaysRetainTaskState" isn't even necessary - system will lead you to activity B even with default "false" value if you return to you task quickly (according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always, system will only reset task state "if the user hasn't visited the task for a certain amount of time, such as 30 minutes").